# How do I add this code to a method using ASM?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

How can I insert this code into a method in a Java class file using the ASM library?

```
long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;            
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

runtime.gc();

long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();            
double memoryUsage=(double)memory/MEGABYTE;
```

Comment: Question is unclear. What have you tried and what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: This would be the perfect use case for [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), which also modifies class files, but allows you to implement the feature at a higher level. If you consider this option, I'll turn it into an answer for you.

Answer (score 6):

The ASM package knows a utility called the [`ASMifier`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifier.html). This utility can be used to translate a compiled class into instructions for ASM to create this code. You could implement the code, use the ASMifier to read it and copy the created instructions into a new ASM [`ClassWriter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html) that appends the required method to a byte stream it receives from an ASM [`ClassReader`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html).

If this does not make sense to you: Read the [ASM documentation](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf). It is a great document and you will be able to understand how to do this with the above guidance after you read it.

Comment: You can find some information about installing and using ASMifier 5 [here](http://xiantrimble.com/blog/2014/03/23/installing-asmifier/).  This version of ASMifier will work with Java 8 class files.